# Using MethodInvoker without Invoke

Tags: c#, user-interface, multithreading, lambda

I am writing GUI applications for some time now and one thing I always use are MethodInvoker + lambda functions to do cross-thread access.

From the examples I find I always see stuff like this:

**Version 1**

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
    {
        Label1.Text = "Foobar";
    });
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Foobar";
}
```

However this leads to code-duplication --> major baddie to me.

So what's wrong with this?

**Version 2**

```
MethodInvoker updateText = new MethodInvoker(() => 
    {
        Label1.Text = "Foobar";
    });

if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(updateText);
}
else
{
    updateText();
}
```

Now I have the functionality bundled in one variable and call it with Invoke or as a function pointer when appropriate. Is version 2 worse performance-wise? Or is i bad practice to use anonymous functions for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing's wrong with it... but you can add an extension method to make it all somewhat nicer:

```
public static void InvokeIfNecessary(this Control control,
                                     MethodInvoker action)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
this.InvokeIfNecessary(() => Label1.Text = "Foobar");
```

Much neater :)

There is a *very slight* performance drawback from creating a delegate when you don't need to, but it's almost certainly insignificant - concentrate on writing clean code.

Note that even if you don't want to do that, you can still make your variable declaration simpler in your existing code:

```
MethodInvoker updateText = () => Label1.Text = "Foobar";
```

That's one benefit of using a separate variable - you don't need the `new MethodInvoker` bit to tell the lambda expression what type of delegate you want...

Comment: Nice, thought me on 2 counts :-) Did not know about the even shorter Lambda option. Also, I think the extension method is even more elegant. It enables me to emphasize what I'm doing even more (InvokeIfRequired). This it necessary to give that second argument to Invoke though? At least 'Form' has a single arg overload?

Comment: @Nebula: Nope, looks like you're right. I was looking at the more general `ISynchronizeInvoke` version first. Will edit for this case.

Comment: alright, thanks. I have actually tested this approach just now and I am very happy with it. It makes for nice clean code. I have added a `control.IsDisposed` and `control.Disposing` guard to make it production worthy, thanks again!

Comment: Scratch that, adding control.IsDisposed and control.Disposing doesn't add any safety, I'll solve premaure closing o my form elsewhere.

Comment: could you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961404/invalideoperationexception-invoke#16961404 and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

> Is version 2 worse performance-wise? Or is i bad practice to use anonymous functions for this?

No version 2 is better, don't worry about performance problems with it. Instead of using an anonymous function you could also define a method:

```
public void SetLabelTextToFooBar()
{
    Label1.Text = "Foobar";
}
```

and then:

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    Invoke(SetLabelTextToFooBar);
}
else
{
    SetLabelTextToFooBar();
}
```

or simply use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which will automatically execute all callbacks (such as `RunWorkerCompleted` and `ProgressChanged`) on the main UI thread so that you don't need to check for `InvokeRequired`.

Comment: For this example I agree with you. When you have a more real-life example the amount of small wrapper methods tend to grow quite fast however. When I use background workers to do a lot of UI updates for instance I tend to keep the amount of work in an Invoke as small as possible. This means that I would have to make a lot of functions to do this wich tends to get obscure over time.

Answer (score 2):

Another practice on doing it:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
{
     Label1.Text = "Foobar";
});
```