# InvalideOperationException / invoke

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, invoke

the following code is used to trigger invoke (code is reduced, i left out the error handling in this example to make it more clear)

```
public static void InvokeIfNecessary(this Control control, MethodInvoker methodInvoker)
{
    if (control != null && !control.IsDisposed && !control.Disposing)
    {

        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(methodInvoker);
        }
        else
        {
            methodInvoker();
        }
    }
}
```

Normally it works fine, but sometimes if i call a method of a Form an InvalidOperationException is given. Schematic method to be called

```
// in a Frm2:
internal void UpdateSomething()
{
    List<NO> myObjects = frmMain.NO.GetNOs();

    if (null != myObjects)
    {
        this.InvokeIfNecessary(() =>
        {
            layoutControlGroup.BeginUpdate(); // DevExpress Layoutcontrolgroup

            foreach (NO aObject in myObjects)
            {
                if(...) // if already a control for the object exist update it.
                {
                    // update

                }
                else
                {
                    // add item
                    LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem = new LayoutControlItem();
                    // create new control
                    Control control = CreateNewControl(aObject);
                    layoutControlItem.Control = control;
                    // do some stuff with visibility and size of control
                    ...
                    layoutControlGroup.AddItem(layoutControlItem); // <-- And here the InvalidOperationException occurs.
                    /// The message is (translated
                    /// InvalidOperationException was not handled by usercode
                    /// The acces on the Control FrmMain was done from another Thrad then the thread which created it.
                    ...;
                }
            }


            ...;

            layoutControlGroupCA.EndUpdate();
        });
    }
}
```

Well... I must admit that i have a conceptual problem here.

Why is the Exception thrown here?

The Frm2 method creates a new element (In NO there is only a string and a struct with strings and bool). The element is only accessed within the UpdateSomething() method. The layOutControlGroup is a member of Frm2.

So in my opinion only a new Control which shoudl be created in Frm2 Thread should be attached to a Frm2 specific Control.

So why does it insisting in FrmMain? (the main form, which calls the method of the form to inform about an update of items)

P.S. this.InvokeIfRequired <- this is Frm2 actually...

Comment: @KenKin this is a schematic waht the programm is doing. I removed company specific names, and exceptions so that they dont disturb, but only show what the thing does.

Comment: Since you've updated the code, I'm removing the previous comment.

Comment: By and large you shouldn't be checking if you need to invoke.  You should know, at compile time, if a given method is going to be executed from the UI thread or not.  If you're not in the UI thread then call `Invoke`, if you are then don't.  If you're constantly checking even when you know you'll need to invoke it's just wasteful, and occasionally gives you pains in those few cases where `InvokeRequired` is false but you really do need to `Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

So, as we see, there are always trouble with ( begin) invoke.
Use BeginInvoke instead. is my hint.
Usually it says, that begin invoke on controls executes a method in the same thread where the handle was created on.

But as it seems, the handle of form2 is not been created in the same thread, OR perhaps it is not present yet.
Try to check this and verify this, please.

Ah. by the way, flag exceptions, clr, in visual studio, when they are thrown. This helps to spot the error.

Comment: If i let display ((Control)this).IsHandleCreated at the point where it breaks, it shows true. As this is Frm2, shouldn't InvokeIfNecessary shouldn't invoke in the correct context where the handle was created? How could I see (VisualStudio 2012) in which thread an object was created?

Comment: The problem is in Your first snippet, as it looks for me.
And no, i had to dig into settings to find out, which thread created the handle. But there are surely methods to retrieve it.

Comment: Hi, nice explaination, but i found the problem. It was in a completly other class then where the debugger stopped. (the object was accessed in other class to log that something failed (should only be classname)) . Was found now over the list of active threads. But i'm still curious why it shows that the AddItem line would cause the issue.

Comment: it is due to the "where did the exception ran into NO handler".

And that is ,where Your line is. I suppose.

But, can You tell, how to get the handles with their threads, please ?

Comment: I cannot tell. I looked through the list of active threads (Ctrl+D,T) and what they are doing in the moment the exception. In that moment the logger tried to access the Control given to InvokeIfNecessary and tried to log that invoke could not be done, because there was no handle created. On this machine it seems to be at the same time when the Control is accessed a second time (because now the handle is created, the InvokeIfNecessary is called, and funilly it stopped while it logs because log could not access control.)

Comment: Ah, this . I know that. Sometimes You need a handle a little bit earlier. This can be also achieved. CreateHandle must be called explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you checked `InvokeRequired` with a wrong control.

What you needed to check with `InvokeRequired` is `layoutControlGroup`, but your extension method checks on form's with the code `this.InvokeIfNecessary` where `this` is Frm2.

Also, you invoked `layoutControlGroup.BeginUpdate()` but `layoutControlGroupCA.EndUpdate()`, seems not symmetric of the usage.

A correction of the code might be:

```
internal void UpdateSomething() {
    var myObjects=frmMain.NO.GetNOs();

    if(null!=myObjects) {
        MethodInvoker beginUpdate=() => layoutControlGroup.BeginUpdate();
        MethodInvoker endUpdate=() => layoutControlGroup.EndUpdate();

        layoutControlGroup.InvokeIfNecessary(beginUpdate);

        foreach(NO aObject in myObjects)
            if(SomeCondition) {
                // update
            }
            else {
                LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem=new LayoutControlItem();
                Control control=CreateNewControl(aObject);
                layoutControlItem.Control=control;

                MethodInvoker addItem=
                    () => {
                        layoutControlGroup.AddItem(layoutControlItem);
                    };

                layoutControlGroup.InvokeIfNecessary(addItem);
            }

        layoutControlGroup.InvokeIfNecessary(endUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but.. that is not the solution. Also Visual Studio always pointed at the line (stop when exception is thrown) it stalled at another method. By the way: layoutControlGroup is a DevExpress element, which does not inherit from control. Therefore layoutControlGroup.InvokeIfNecessary will not work. I#m also a bit curious about a detail in your explaination. As the controls are from Form2, how should it happen that they are not in the context of Form2? As written in original post, the layoutControlGroup is a member variable of Frm2

Comment: @Offler: `InvokeRequired` is used to check whether the invocation of desired control is in the current context. If it returns true, then it's not. The return value of `InvokeRequired` of the container might not be the same with the targeting control.

Comment: can you explain in which case the container (on which controls only can be added from his context?) can have another context then its controls?

Comment: Yes. Create a `Button` named `button1` on your form, and test the following code:  `Debug.Print("{0}", button1.InvokeRequired);

 (new Thread(() => {
  Debug.Print("{0}", button1.InvokeRequired);
 })).Start();`
You'll get different result of `InvokeRequired`.

Comment: @Offler: Since this does not solve your issue, I'm ready to delete it. Sorry for that I haven't update my license of DevExpress ..

Comment: @Servy: Why recover the content of my deleted answer .. ?

Comment: @KenKin Why remove it?  Mostly because it's occasionally helpful to see what a deleted answer is.  Perhaps is was right, or close enough to right, and it could be fixed up enough to be workable, perhaps it's abusive/inappropriate and should be flagged, perhaps it's an answer I would consider writing, but it's wrong for reasons I haven't yet seen; seeing that someone else posted the answer and deleted it when it was shown to be wrong can be helpful.