# databind datagridview in multithreadded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

Im trying to databind my data grid view from a timer using multi threading. THe timer is there as we need it to show live data.

The code im using is -

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = JobManager.GetTodaysJobs();
        trd = new Thread(StartTimer);
        trd.Start();
    }

    void StartTimer()
    {
        timer1.Start();
        LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        dt = JobManager.GetTodaysJobs();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
```

However, I get the following error -

*Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.*

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Cheers

Comment: enter that error message into a search engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513364/thread-error-in-c-sharp-windows-form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947718/using-methodinvoker-without-invoke

Comment: please search for error before posting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot update UI elements from A thread that is not the creator of these objects.

change your method like this:

```
void LoadData()
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(InnerLoadData));
}

void InnerLoadData()
{
    dt = JobManager.GetTodaysJobs();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```